# SDE driven by fractional Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, brownian-motion

Let $B^H$ be a fraction Brownian motion of Hurst parameter $H$. Consider the SDE driven by $B^H$ as below:

$$dX_t = b(t,X_t)dt + a(t,X_t)dB^H_t,\quad \forall t\ge 0.$$

I am looking for references that discuss its wellposedness (under suitable conditions for $b,a$)

Comment: @ThomasKojar Do you know by chance the related references, even for some concrete or particular coefficients?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.0893

Comment: @ThomasKojar One more question is why Picard's iteration may fail here?

Comment: Add that in your above question so that someone can give a full answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When $H > 1/2$, one can interpret the integral as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral and one gets solutions by classical Picard iteration in $C^\alpha$ for $1/2 < \alpha < H$. It's not hard to see that $a$ being $C^{1/2}$ in time and $C^2$ in space is sufficient to get well-posedness. (For $b$, continuous in time and Lipschitz in space is always enough.)

When $1/4 < H < 1/2$ the standard way of interpreting this SDE is as a rough differential equation driven by the canonical lift of fractional Brownian motion. When $H > 1/3$, this is covered for example in my book "A course on rough paths" with Peter Friz. See Chapter 8 for the solution theory of general RDEs and Chapter 10.3 for the treatment of fractional Brownian motion. Going all the way down to $H > 1/4$ was originally done by Coutin and Qian, "Stochastic analysis, rough path analysis and fractional Brownian motions", PTRF (2002). (This of course relies on Terry Lyons's 1998 paper "Differential equations driven by rough signals" for the analytical aspects.) Here one needs more regularity for $a$, for example $C^1$ in time and $C^4$ in space is good enough. Note that even there solutions are obtained by Picard iteration, but the space in which the iteration takes place is more involved (it is a space of "controlled rough paths").

These notions of solutions are natural in the sense that they arise as limits of solutions to the ordinary differential equations obtained by smoothing $B$ with a mollifier and taking limits (in the case $H = 1/2$ this leads to Stratonovich solutions).

This approach *fails* when $H \le 1/4$ and there are very good arguments suggesting that this failure is unrecoverable. Another notion of solution is given by interpreting the integral as a Skorokhod integral (this is used in the references given by Thomas Kojar, although the second reference also discusses the classical solutions when $H > 1/2$). This notion is genuinely *different*, i.e. even for $a$'s and $b$'s in the intersection of their domain of applicability, the two notions give distinct solutions. It is also *unphysical* in the sense that if $X$ is a scalar random variable and $F$ is a stochastic process in the domain of the integration operator, one in general has $\int XF\,dB \neq X\int F\,dB$.

Comment: Being nonlocal in probability space is a pretty unintuitive property. Is there some interpretation of what a nonlocal integral means, not necessarily physical? I mean morally speaking, formally what you wrote is very clear.

Comment: It should be noted that there have been construction of rough paths above fBm for any $H$ by Nualart and Tindel.

Comment: Thank you very kindly Professor Hairer for the detailed explanation

Comment: @user479223 Correct, it was actually shown by Lyons and Victoir how to lift any Hölder continuous function to a rough path. However this lift relies on a number of arbitrary choices so isn't canonical in any sense.

Comment: @NateRiver I just changed what I meant by "unphysical" in the answer. It's not quite equivalent to what I wrote before but it's maybe more intuitive.

Comment: Also, see this paper https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/07362994.2017.1423231 for why Skorokhod integration is unphysical in an insider trading model.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of references one suggestion is ["Stochastic differential equations driven by fractional Brownian motions"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.0893.pdf) and the book ["Stochastic Calculus
for Fractional Brownian Motion and Application"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-75873-0).

Also, answering the question in the comment

> One more question is why Picard's iteration may fail here?

We follow ["Itô type stochastic differential equations driven by fractional Brownian motions of Hurst parameter H>1/2"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01137).

Consider the Picard iteration recursive formula

$$x_{n}(t):=x(0)+\int^{t}_{0}b(s,x_{n-1}(s))ds+\int^{t}_{0}\sigma(s,x_{n-1}(s))dB_{H}(s).$$

By Itô-isometry for fBM (see Theorem 3.11.1 in the above book or other references in  [Isometry for the stochastic integral wrt fractional Brownian motion for random processes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280791/isometry-for-the-stochastic-integral-wrt-fractional-brownian-motion-for-random-p)) in terms of Malliavin derivative

$$E\left[\left(\int \sigma(s, x_{n−1}(s))dB_{H}(s)\right)^{2} \right]$$

$$=\int\int\phi(u,v) E\left[\sigma(s, x_{n−1}(u))\sigma(s, x_{n−1}(v))\right]dudv$$

$$+\int\int E\left[\sigma_{x}(s, x_{n−1}(u))\sigma_{x}(s, x_{n−1}(v))D_{v}^{\phi}x_{n−1}(u)D_{u}^{\phi}x_{n−1}(v)\right]dudv,$$

where $\phi(u,v):=H(2H − 1)|u − v|^{2H−2}$, $\sigma_{x}$ the partial derivative of $\sigma(t, x)$ with respect to $x$ and $D_{u}^{\phi}$ is defined in terms of the regular Malliavin derivative

$$D_{u}^{\phi}F(\omega):=\int \phi(u,r)D_{r}F(\omega)dr.$$

So the issue here is that in order to get $L^{2}$-convergence, as we repeat the recursion we are forced to repeatedly control the $L^{2}$-norm of increasingly many iterated Malliavin derivatives, which in turn restricts the function space we are allowed to work with for the coefficients $b,\sigma$.